# Are possessives determiners(his, my, her...) preferred to the definite article ('the')

Tags: differences, possessives, definite-articles

I have a question regarding the usage of possessives in substitution of “the”: Are possessives preferred to the definite article 'the' in some occasions and why?

For example, I found the relationship between 'children' and 'parents' is always denoted by possessives instead of 'the' when these two are used in close proximity. While in the case of the relationship between a human and his or her body part, both 'the' and possessives read natural to me, although 'the' seems more preferred to possessives, as shown below:

> **1.**
>
> a) The government helped these children to meet *their* parents.
>
> b) The government helped these children to meet *the* parents. (?)

> **2.**
>
> a) He hit me on *the* head.
>
> b) He hit me on *my* head.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&smoothing=3&content=preferred+than%2Cpreferred+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreferred%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Grice advises that sufficient (but not superfluous) reference be given. With 'The government helped these children to meet the parents,' we're looking back to see when these parents were first mentioned, and whose parents they are. Using 'their' is logical here. // 'He hit me on the head' involves a fixed phrase; although 'my' is also totally acceptable here, it is less idiomatic (you can check in ngrams yourself) and no more precising.

Comment: @LPH@Edwin Ashworth, thank you both for answering my question.  Your answers are definitely helping me to get more insights into this possessive-definite issue, but may I still ask why possessive is the more frequent choice in example 1, and 'the' in example 2? It seems to me that the referential effect of the two determiners is pretty similar, and I really can not feel the subtle nuances among the different preference.  Is there any intuition which guides you guys to accept one rather than the other?

Comment: Out of context, _the parents_ doesn't make it clear that it refers to the children's own parents. _He hit me_ makes it clear that it was the speaker who was hit, so they don't need to specify that it was their own head that took the blow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first sentence is the correct one when the parents in question are the children's parents; the second one wouldn't be used at all.
2. Cases of "hit me on **my** head" are [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_start=1800&content=hit+me+on+the+head%2Chit+me+on+my+head&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20me%20on%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20me%20on%20my%20head%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chit%20me%20on%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20me%20on%20my%20head%3B%2Cc0), people write almost exclusively "hit me on **the** head".

Here is a fairly comprehensive account by a certain [Rachel, Moderator at GrammarExchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/the-or-possessive-adjective-for-part-of-the-body), in answer to this question: "- Uncle patted me on [the, my] shoulder. As to this sentence, some people say that the definite article is correct, some say that the possessive is correct, and some say that both are correct. Would you please tell me which opinion I should follow? If both are correct, which is preferred?".

> In English, it's more frequent to use possessives when talking about
> the parts
> of someone's body.
> We would say:
>
> "¢ The football player broke his arm while making the play.
> "¢ Put your ankle right here so we can take an x-ray.
> "¢ You're so beautiful! Your smile, your eyes, your teeth your hair – are in a class beyond compare!
>
> ---
>
> However, in a slightly different grammatical construction, "the" is often used in prepositional phrases related to the object of a clause (or the subject of a passive clause) when talking about parts of the body.
>
> "¢ Look me in the eye!
>
> "¢ Craig was hit on the head by a falling plant. Fortunately, he escaped injury.
>
> "¢ Apply the ointment to the skin and bandage lightly.
>
> ---
>
> Sometimes "the" is used in prepositional phrases after "be" + an adjective:
>
> "¢ That store has clothes for men who are broad in the shoulders and narrow in the hips.
>
> ---
>
> When speaking generally, or medically, you see and hear more instances of "the" with parts of the body than you do when speaking to somebody or of another person:
>
> "¢ Then the fever spikes, often as high as 104 or 105 F, at the same time a red blotchy rash surfaces on the face, along the hairline and behind the ears. (Description of measles from mayoclinic.org)
>
> "¢ Other researchers, including Dr. Oberdörster's father, Günter Oberdörster, a professor of environmental medicine at the University of Rochester, have  shown that such particles can enter the brain. (from an article on nanotechnology in today's New York Times)
>
> ---
>
> In your sentence, "Uncle patted me on the shoulder" would be correct because of the prepositional phrase "on the shoulder." However, in an intimate, friendly conversation as this one might be, "Uncle patted me on my shoulder and told me to go to bed early" would also be correct.

Comment: There are exceptions where 2b works (e.g. the children are orphans, whom the government takes to meet their prospective foster parents), but those are very narrow exceptions. In 99.9% of cases you would use "their parents".